# Importing and naming a remote file

Tags: python

I have written some code to read the contents from a specific url:

```
import requests
import os

def read_doc(doc_ID):
    filename = doc_ID + ".txt"
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
    my_url = encode_url(doc_ID) #this is a call to another function that would encode the url
    my_response = requests.get(my_url)
    if my_response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        return my_response.text
    return None
```

This checks if there's a file named `doc_ID.txt` (where `doc_ID` could be any name provided). And if there's no such file, it would read the contents from a specific url and would return them. What I would like to do is to store those returned contents in a file called `doc_ID.txt`. That is, I would like to finish my function by creating a new file in case it didn't exist at the beginning.

How can I do that? I tried this:

```
my_text = my_response.text
output = os.rename(my_text, filename)
return output
```

but then, the actual contents of the file would become the name of the file and I would get an error saying the filename is too long.

Comment: Hi @Me All.  Why are you renaming a file which does not exist?  You can write to a new file using simple file operations in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue I think I'm seeing is that you want to put the contents of your request's response into the file, rather than naming the file with the contents. The code below should create a file with the filename you want, and insert the text from your response!

```
import requests
import os

def read_doc(doc_ID):
    filename = doc_ID + ".txt"
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        my_url = encode_url(doc_ID) #this is a call to another function that would encode the url
        my_response = requests.get(my_url)
        if my_response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
            with open(filename, "w") as file:
                file.write(my_response.text)
                return file
    return None
```

Comment: Can I add a `return file` as a last line within the `with` section? Because I need to return the file

Comment: Ah, yeah, sorry! For sure you can add `return file` after the `file.write` line.

Comment: I added the "return" line to the original answer.

Answer (score 0):

To write the response text to the file, you can simply use python `file` object, https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

```
with open(filename, "w") as file: 
  file.write(my_text)
```